# How to make click on the Update Button in the shopping Cart Page - Url="http://live.guru99.com/"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

[image]Even though x-path  picking  the element , and i tried with java executor, but at the time of code run , it is only able to click on update button for  the first element in the cart . Below is the Code :

Here once after placing 3 products in the cart i have added there text boxes into a list :

I have attached the image :
     Url="http://live.guru99.com/"

```
List<WebElement> li2 =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product- 
cart-actions']/input"));


for(int j=0;j<li2.size();j++)
    {

        if(j==0)
        {
            li2.get(j).clear();
        li2.get(j).sendKeys("4");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update']")).click();
        li2 =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/input"));
        }
        else if(j==1)
        {
            li2.get(j).clear();
            li2.get(j).sendKeys("2");
            //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit']")));
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit']")).isDisplayed();

            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit']"));
            try {
                if (element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()) {
                    System.out.println("Clicking on element with using java script click");

                    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unable to click on element");
                }
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                System.out.println("Element is not attached to the page document "+ e.getStackTrace());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Element was not found in DOM "+ e.getStackTrace());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to click on element "+ e.getStackTrace());
            }
        //  if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            //  element.click();
            //}


            li2 =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/input"));
        }


        else
        {
            li2.get(j).clear();
            li2.get(j).sendKeys("3");

            WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update']"));

        if (element1.isDisplayed()) {
             element1.click();
            }       
        }
```

Comment: @guy : can you plz look at  this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the culprit:-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit']"));
```

So when you have multiple elements with same locators, `WebDriver` clicks on the first and moves ahead. So if you want to click the `2nd` or `3rd` element you can modify your xpath something like:-

```
.//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit'][2]   -- For 2nd Element
```

OR

```
.//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit'][3]  -- For 3rd element.
```

But it won't be a nice approach there may be multiple in future and you won't go around adding the index for each and every element.

Best approach would be to identify the `update` button with reference to the `product name` which is `unique` in your case.

Comment: It's is not working , i tried the same . adding[2] and [3]  is not picking product

Comment: //tr[2]//td[@class='product-cart-actions']/button[@title='Update' and @type='submit']                            this works :chaged the tr

Comment: i have just given a rough idea. I din't check the `html` glad its working for you.